# Google Analytics Custom URL Reorting

Tags: url, analytics, utm, google-analytics-firebase

I have used custom url builder to build custom url and submitted to different directories.

URL is

```
?utm_source=directory&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=DirectoryReferrals
```

Now i am stuck with reporting coz it shows source as "directory" thats what i need it to show but full referral part is showing as not set.

How can i get full url of the referral source? Need help as soon as possible.

Is there any way to get the url of the referral?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misunderstanding the usage of the utm_source parameter in the context of custom campaigns. It wouldn't be used to get the source URL that you used when tagging your campaign, but rather it should show the source where the campaign is originating from, for example advertiser, site (eg. "google"), publication (eg. "newsletter", "billboard"). More information on campaigns can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863. Also some good info on why you are getting "not set": https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en.

If you are trying to see where traffic is coming from, eg. www.google.com, www.facebook.com, then you wouldn't use custom campaigns for that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks guys, yes i know how to use custom campaign. Maybe i didnt post the question correctly. the reports (past) which was collected by google analytics shows source as directory because i had used utm_source=directory and i was hoping that if i can find the real source for those old reports.

Comment: now i have changed the utm_source accordingly. but i was not able to see original domain (source for the old ones).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nyuen, you might have misunderstood the concept of UTM tracking code.

I would suggest that if you want to know that from which referral source you got the traffic then you can write it under UTM_SOURCE.

Suppose if you have promoted your post in the Facebook and Google, then in the UTM_SOURCE you can write Facebook there.

**Example:**

```
http://www.example.com?utm_source=Twitter&utm_medium=Webinar_Tweet&utm_term=Service_Cloud&utm_campaign=Social
```

Hope this Works :)

Answer (score -1):

You always able to find your refferal traffic under > Acquisition > referral even you tagged link with utm.

If it's not help, please upload some screenshot.

Comment: under > Acquisition > referral it shows the source name i had entered in the url builder. i need it to show full url